# Angular no encuentra FormControl de un formulario

Tags: javascript, angular, formularios

tengo el siguiente formulario en Angular

```
 <form [formGroup]="formulario" (ngSubmit)="preregistrarUsuario(formulario)">
            <label for="tipo">Tipo de usuario</label>
            <div class="form-group">
              <select class="form-control" id="tipo" formControlName="tipo">
                <option value="Titular">Titular</option>
                <option value="Deysa">DEySA</option>
                <option value="Docente">Docente</option>
                <option value="Alumno">Alumno</option>
              </select>
              <p *ngIf="formulario.controls"  class="error">Selecciona un tipo de usuario.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="correo">Correo electrónico</label>
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="correo" formControlName="correo"/>
              <p class="error" *ngIf='formulario.controls.correo.errors.required'>Escribe tu correo electrónico</p>
              <p class="error" *ngIf='formulario.controls.correo.errors.pattern'>Formato de correo invalido</p>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group text-center">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-guinda">Pre registrar</button>
            </div>
          </form>
```

Y la siguiente clase:

```
    export class UsuariosAdminComponent implements OnInit {

    formulario: FormGroup;

     // @HostBinding('class') classes = '';
     usuario: Usuario = new Usuario();

      constructor(private titleService: Title, private apiTtService: ApiTtService, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
        this.titleService.setTitle('Usuarios');
  this.formulario = this.formBuilder.group({
          tipo: ['', Validators.required], //Le decimos que es requerido
          correo: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern("^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,4})$")]]
        });

      }

      ngOnInit() {
      /*  this.usuario = {

        }*/

      }

      preregistrarUsuario(formulario)
      {
        const tipo=formulario.controls.tipo.value;
        let correo=formulario.controls.correo.value;

        console.log(tipo);
        console.log(correo);
        console.log(formulario);

    /*
        this.apiTtService.preregistrarUsuario(this.usuario).subscribe(
          res =>
          {
            console.log(res);
          },
          err =>
          {
            console.log(err);
          })
          */
      }
    }
```

Mi problema es que no me reconoce el control correo cuando hago el ngIf, me aparece el siguiente error 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo curioso es que cuando inspecciono la consola si existen esos formControl
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguna idea de como solucionar este problema? ya estuve investigando y nada me funciona, esta manera de manejar los formularios lo vi en un tutorial y en el tutorial funciona a la perfeccion.

Comment: Prueba a acceder a los controles así:  formulario.controls['tipo'].value

Answer (score 1):

Creo que no es un error de código, me imagino que la aplicación funciona correctamente. Lo que te marca el error es una extensión(por ejemplo: TSLint) que tendrás instalada en el Visual Studio Code o en el editor que gastes, puedes probar deshabilitando la extensión y ver si el error continua.

Si gastas el Visual Studio Code mira a ver que extensión tienes instalada, creo que hay una que esta obsoleta [TSLint (deprecated) - egamma](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eg2.tslint)  . Prueba con esta [TSLint - Microsoft](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.vscode-typescript-tslint-plugin).

Saludos.

**Actualizado:**

Hay varias formas para arreglar esto, pero creo que la mas adecuada es la que te han puesto en el comentario:

```html
<p class="error" *ngIf="formulario.controls['correo'].errors.pattern">Formato de correo invalido</p>
```

Comment: Hola! Como se puede (si es que es factible) que en vez de usar la directiva ngIf para mostrar el error, este venga retornado por el componente desde el archivo .ts? Para que la logica del html quede limpia y sin esos detalles.